# Caesar Cipher Decoder just encodes again?

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to create a Caesar Cipher program, to encode and decode a string from a text file. The program can encode perfectly, but for some reason the decode method is just encoding again. Wondering what I have done wrong to the decode method?

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Project03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        CaesarCipher CaesarCipher = new CaesarCipher("", 0);
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner intoff = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type E to encrypt a file, or D to decrypt a file");
        String pick = choice.nextLine();
        if (pick.toLowerCase().equals("e")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the file path of the text you'd like to encrypt: ");
            File file = new File(choice.nextLine());
            Scanner textfile = new Scanner(file);
            String line = textfile.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the offset you would like to use (must be 1-25)");
            int offset = intoff.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Name the file you would like to output to");
            String TextOutput = choice.nextLine();
            System.out.println(CaesarCipher.encode(line, offset));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(TextOutput, true));
            System.setOut(out);
        } else if (pick.toLowerCase().equals("d")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the file path of the text you'd like to decrypt: ");
            File file = new File(choice.nextLine());
            Scanner textfile = new Scanner(file);
            String line = textfile.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the offset you would like to use (must be 1-25)");
            int offset = choice.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Name the file you would like to output to");
            String TextOutput = choice.nextLine();
            System.out.println(CaesarCipher.decode(CaesarCipher.encode(line, offset), offset));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(TextOutput, true));
            System.setOut(out);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Something went Wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

CaesarCipher Class:

```
public class CaesarCipher {
    public CaesarCipher(String enc, int offset){
        enc="";
        offset=0;
    }

    public static String decode(String enc, int offset) {
        return encode(enc, 26-offset);
    }

    public static String encode(String enc, int offset) {
        offset = offset % 26 + 26;
        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
        for (char i : enc.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i)) {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                    encoded.append((char) ('A' + (i - 'A' + offset) % 26 ));
                } else {
                    encoded.append((char) ('a' + (i - 'a' + offset) % 26 ));
                }
            } else {
                encoded.append(i);
            }
        }
        return encoded.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `System.out.println(CaesarCipher.decode(line, offset))` when decoding instead of `System.out.println(CaesarCipher.decode(CaesarCipher.encode(line, offset), offset))`, assuming that `line` has already been encoded?